# How to use pathlib along with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pathlib

I would like to use relative paths along with subprocess module in order to be able to run different executables.

For getting relative paths and, after reading different threads, I think pathlib module is the best option to do that.

Let assume I have the python script in a particular folder in Windows. Inside it (the previous folder), I have other folders with the executables I want to run. Here it is when subprocess module comes in. However, I do not know how to include the relative paths created with pathlib module into subprocess args field.

From subprocess API I can read that 'args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string'.

```
import pathlib
import subprocess

in_file_1 = pathlib.Path.cwd() / "folder2" / "folder3" / "whatever.exe"

p = subprocess.Popen(str(in_file_1), shell = True)
```

I would expect to see the whatever.exe process running on the administrator tasks but the process is not started. How can I achieve that? Is there something I am ingoring? Should I just give the relative path from where the python script is saved?

Comment: I just tested your snippet and everything works as expected. Are you sure about your `whatever.exe` location? Why do you want to use the current working dir?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about the `whatever.exe` location. If I save the python script in the same folder as the `whatever.exe` the above code works but If I save it upstream `whatever.exe` does not work even specifying the relative path to it.

Comment: You are using `pathlib.Path.cwd()` so what matters is the current dir when you launch the script, not where the script is located.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do with ´in_file_1´ in order to obtain the current location of the python script. But even with that, I cannot make it work. Thank you for your comments @nicoco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the [**c**urrent **w**orking **d**irectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), which is what `pathlib.Path.cwd()` returns, with the script's location.

If you want the script's dir, you can use `__file__`, for instance like this:

```
import pathlib

cwd = pathlib.Path.cwd()
script_file = pathlib.Path(__file__)
script_location = script_file.parent

print("The current dir is", pathlib.Path.cwd())
print("The current script is", script_file)
print("The current script's dir is", script_file.parent)
```

which will return:

```
The current dir is /home/nicoco
The current script is /tmp/so.py
The current script's dir is /tmp
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @nicoco. Now it is working perfectly. I did not realize about the script's location! I have just put ´whatever.exe´ as arg for ´subprocess.Popen´  and specified the path with cwd argument. Thank you once again!